# Alias the return type of a const overloaded function

Tags: c++, c++11, constants, decltype

I have the following overloaded function :

```
template<size_t N, typename T>
auto get(const T & _t) -> decltype(std::get<...>(_t)) {
    ...
}

template<size_t N, typename T>
auto get(T & _t) -> decltype(std::get<...>(_t)) {
    ...
}
```

First question is :

does the first one uses `std::get(const tuple<_Elements...>& __t)`
 and the second one `std::get(tuple<_Elements...>& __t)` ??

now I want to alias the return type of my new function `get`  :

```
using type = typename decltype(aux::get<I>(data))::type;
```

which one is used here ? the const or not ? and How can I choose ? I would like to alias both !! `data` is non-const

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the first one uses the `const` overload and the second one the non-`const` one. That's because `_t` is `const` in the first case and non-`const` in the second one.

Which one is used in the type alias depends on the type of `data`. Is it `const`? If so, the `const` overload is aliased. If not, the non-`const` one is.

To get a "virtual value" of any type, you can use `std::declval`. This code would alias the `const` version:

```
using type = typename decltype(aux::get<I>(std::declval<const YourTypeHere>()))::type;
```

Comment: `data` is non-const, how can I get the const type : ` typename decltype(aux::get<I>(...))::type`  when the argument is const, I don't want to add a new variable